# How to order the item categories in linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, c#-4.0

I am having 20 records

I want to order the records in terms of `Priority` field.

`Priority` field is having 3 values( `High, Medium, Low` )

I want to display the records in `High, Medium, Low` records in sequence respectively.

```
var groupedRecords = records.GroupBy(x => x.Priority == "High") // confused here...
```

Note: I want to get **first** all High records, **then** Medium records and **atlast** Low records.

Comment: Do you have to deal in strings? If you can still change these, please consider migrating Priority to enum. Will make your life much easier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to *order* the list, so use the `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending` extension.

```
var orderedRecords = records.OrderByDescending(x => x.Priority == "High").ThenByDescending(x => x.Priority == "Medium");
```

Comment: For medium and low records, how to group ?

Comment: @HimBromBeere You're wrong. A `Predicate<T>` is essentially a `Func<T,bool>` so this will compile.

Comment: Simple and Clear Solution.

Answer (score 6):

Why not *map* the priorities to, say, integers:

```
  High   -> 1
  Medium -> 2
  Low    -> 3
```

So it can be something like this:

```
  var groupedRecords = records.
    OrderBy(x => (x.Priority == "High") 
      ? 1 
      : (x.Priority == "Medium") ? 2 : 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
var groupedRecords = records.OrderBy(x => x.Priority == "High").ThenBy(x => x.Priority == "Medium").ThenBy(x => x.Priority == "Low");
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is

```
 var result = records.Where(x => x.Priority == "High")
                     .ToList()
                     .AddRange(records.Where(x => x.Priority == "Medium").ToList())
                     .AddRange(records.Where(x => x.Priority == "Low").ToList());
```